# Shortcut button to switch between two menus in android

Tags: android, gridview, menu

In my app i have to develop a menu using grid view with the icons and a shortcut button for easy switching of language options.  So when the user clicks this button, 'English Menu' should switch to 'Urdu Menu' and vice-versa. So do i have to make two menu activities : one in English and on in Urdu and keep switching between them using intent or i should use toggle button instead ? Please suggest. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I added all the menu items (in your case, both English AND Urdu menu items) into my menu xml file. And I grouped them as you see here ([Menu Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html)). And per button click, I set their visibility to either true or false.

(Edit) This is a function in Android Menu class: 
setGroupVisible(int group, boolean visible)
Show or hide all menu items that are in the given group.